# Use cases for GnuPG's --(import|export)-options (import|export)-(clean|minimal)

Tags: gnupg

I'm wondering in which scenarios I would make use of GnuPG's non-default `--(import|export)-options` `(import|export)-(clean|minimal)`?

The only practical use case I can imagine is to export my public key with the command `gpg --armor --export --export-options export-minimal` in order to publicize it on my homepage or distribute it via e-mail so that others can encrypt messages for me or verify signatures I made.

Answer (score 2):

Debian maintainers sometimes use keys exported with `export-minimal` in their source packages to verify new upstream releases. That way the keys take up less space.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can give you a hint as to what might be useful.

https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-2.0/GPG-Input-and-Output.html

> ```
> --export-options parameters
>     This is a space or comma delimited string that gives options for
>     exporting keys. Options can be prepended with a ‘no-’ to give the
>     opposite meaning. The options are:
>
>     export-local-sigs
>       Allow exporting key signatures marked as "local". This is not
>       generally useful unless a shared keyring scheme is being used.
>       Defaults to no.
>
>     export-attributes
>       Include attribute user IDs (photo IDs) while exporting. This is
>       useful to export keys if they are going to be used by an OpenPGP
>       program that does not accept attribute user IDs.
>       Defaults to yes.
>
>     export-sensitive-revkeys
>       Include designated revoker information that was marked as
>       "sensitive".
>       Defaults to no.
>
>     export-reset-subkey-passwd
>       When using the --export-secret-subkeys command, this option
>       resets the passphrases for all exported subkeys to empty. This is
>       useful when the exported subkey is to be used on an unattended
>       machine where a passphrase doesn’t necessarily make sense. 
>       Defaults to no.
>
>     export-clean
>       Compact (remove all signatures from) user IDs on the key being
>       exported if the user IDs are not usable. Also, do not export any
>       signatures that are not usable. This includes signatures that were
>       issued by keys that are not present on the keyring. This option is
>       the same as running the --edit-key command "clean" before export
>       except that the local copy of the key is not modified.
>       Defaults to no.
>
>     export-minimal
>       Export the smallest key possible. This removes all signatures
>       except the most recent self-signature on each user ID. This option
>       is the same as running the --edit-key command "minimize" before
>       export except that the local copy of the key is not modified.
>       Defaults to no.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Security Stack Exchange, it would be great if you also highlighted the relevant flags.